# Pass args through rebar shell to erl?

Tags: erlang, rebar, erl

I am using "rebar shell" to test my app. This is documented as:

> Start a shell with project and deps preloaded similar to
>
> ```
> 'erl -pa ebin -pa deps/*/ebin'.
> ```

How do I add extra args to the underlying invocation of 'erl'? For
example, I want to add application specific environment variables and
run a Module/Function. I want to invoke something like:

```
 erl -pa ebin -pa deps/*/ebin -browser_spy browser_exe "/my/dir" -run bs_example test
```

(and I want code:priv_dir to work as it does when using rebar shell,
which the above 'erl' command does not do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You cannot

`rebar shell` does not execute `erl ...` command actually, but only tries to *replicate its behaviour*.

Actually rebar just turns yourself into the shell along with mimicking `-pa` by adding paths with `code:add_pathz`

See [here](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_shell.erl) for implementation details:

> ```
> shell(_Config, _AppFile) ->
>     true = code:add_pathz(rebar_utils:ebin_dir()),
>     %% scan all processes for any with references to the old user and save them to
>     %% update later
>     NeedsUpdate = [Pid || Pid <- erlang:processes(),
>         proplists:get_value(group_leader, erlang:process_info(Pid)) == whereis(user)
>     ],
>     %% terminate the current user
>     ok = supervisor:terminate_child(kernel_sup, user),
>     %% start a new shell (this also starts a new user under the correct group)
>     _ = user_drv:start(),
>     %% wait until user_drv and user have been registered (max 3 seconds)
>     ok = wait_until_user_started(3000),
>     %% set any process that had a reference to the old user's group leader to the
>     %% new user process
>     _ = [erlang:group_leader(whereis(user), Pid) || Pid <- NeedsUpdate],
>     %% enable error_logger's tty output
>     ok = error_logger:swap_handler(tty),
>     %% disable the simple error_logger (which may have been added multiple
>     %% times). removes at most the error_logger added by init and the
>     %% error_logger added by the tty handler
>     ok = remove_error_handler(3),
>     %% this call never returns (until user quits shell)
>     timer:sleep(infinity).
> ```